# MongoDB - How to find() a field in a collection that has a reference to another collection?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, angular-meteor, angular2-meteor

So I have this field `contacts.envCon.name` which is inside the Projects collection but when I see them in mongo they are like this:

```
    "envCon" : {
        "$ref" : "contacts",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5807966090c01f4174cb1714")
    }
```

After doing a simple find based on past ObjectId:

```
db.getCollection('contacts').find({_id:ObjectId("5807966090c01f4174cb1714")})
```

I get the following result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5807966090c01f4174cb1714"),
    "name" : "Terracon"
}
```

---

By the way: I'm using Meteor if there is anyway to do this directly with publish/suscribe methods.

Comment: The way Mongo stores objectid's shouldn't effect you. You should be able to do something like Contacts.find({_id: "5807966090c01f4174cb1714"})

Comment: @Mikkel what I want to do is say retrieve with a find() all projects in project collection and at the same time field `envCon.name` as you can see envCon is part of contacts collection

Comment: Are you using a composite collection here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this *join* inside a publication using the very popular [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package.

With your model:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('projectsWithContacts', {
    find: function() {
        return Projects.find(); // all projects
    },
    children: [
        {
            find: function(p) { // p is one project document
                return Contacts.find(
                    { _id: p.envCon.$id }, // this is the relationship
                    { fields: { name: 1 } }); // only return the name (_id is automatic)
            }
        },
    ]
});
```

Comment: can you please put an example of how this would be achieve bringing all field from `projects` then based on `contacts`ObjectId retrieved field `name`of that `ObjectId`

Comment: thanks Michel. I'll try to make it work ASAP, currently working on another requirement